# What are some good choices to work with JSON in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, json

There are some things around the web but it's hard to tell what the standard is.

I need to do encoding and decoding. So JSON string -> AS object and AS object -> JSON string.

Comment: What do you mean? How to consume JSON in ActionScript? How to create it?

Comment: I need to do encoding and decoding.

So JSON string -> AS object and AS object -> JSON string.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, this is the standard: http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/.

So, for instance, you can use `JSON.decode(s)` and `JSON.encode(o)` to go from string-to-object and object-to-string. I've never had a problem, except that you should wrap it in try/catch during decode because it can throw errors when the JSON is invalid.

Comment: This the standard JSON library for as3 - I've used it successfully on a few projects.